# Installing Python package: setup.py install - error: no commands supplied

Tags: python

- I am trying to install python-pptx-0.5.7 package in windows 7.
         What I did is as follows:

  ```
     1) Downloaded the python-pptx-0.5.7.tar file from website.
     2) Unzipped it and kept it in the Python34/Script folder.
     3) I used command prompt to install the package as
     setup.py install.

     Here is the ouptput of the command that I wrote in command prompt

     c:\Python34\Scripts\python-pptx-0.5.7>setup.py install
     usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help



     error: no commands supplied.
  ```

  The second approach using "pip"

  ```
         c:\Python34\Scripts>pip install python-pptx
  ```

  Collecting python-pptx
  Downloading python-pptx-0.5.7.tar.gz (5.2MB)
  100% |################################| 5.2MB 25kB/s
  Collecting lxml>=3.1.0 (from python-pptx)
  Downloading lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz (3.8MB)
  100% |################################| 3.8MB 41kB/s
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow>=2.6.1 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from     python-pptx)
  Collecting XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 (from python-pptx)
  Downloading XlsxWriter-0.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
  100% |################################| 135kB 62kB/s
  Building wheels for collected packages: python-pptx, lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-pptx
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\praveen\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\1f\fa\42\
  bbc04bb0ef4be4cd49f228cc1fa3280bb99c1a37d3b193b81b
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

  ---

  Failed building wheel for lxml
   Successfully built python-pptx
  Failed to build lxml
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  \r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Answer (score -1):

Please [follow the official Python package installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Packages should be installed like:

```
pip install python-pptx
```

Download is automatic from pypi.python.org.

Comment: I really appreciate the alternative but " pip install python-pptx" does not work in python 3.4.2 in windows 64 bit.  I install all other packages using pip only but this package is unable to install in python 3.4.2

Comment: Morever when I was in office the same above command " setup.py install " was working absolutely fine and when I did the same thing on my personal laptop its just not working at all.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide both full pip command you type and full output of that command?

Comment: @PratikChhapolika: You marked this is solved. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Not solved. I have pasted the output though not in good format.

Comment: @PratikChhapolika: Please read StackOverlow instructions how to use Markdown to format your question. You need to add four spaces at the front of each line containing code. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90407/easy-way-to-indent-code - you can edit your question and fix this.

Comment: lxml error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Failed to build lxml ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command, \r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n" **

Comment: @PratikChhapolika: Please refer to lxml manual how to get it installed on Windows

Comment: I tried that also its saying : "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"     ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *

Comment: What lxml installation instructions you are following? Again please edit the question and include very specific details.

Comment: "pip install lxml." And I am getting the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: Looks like the lxml is not providing binary packages to 64-bit windows yet and it tries to compile from source, assuming you have compiler installed.

Comment: The link which you provided  does not have any file for python 3.4.2 version.

Comment: Hmm. A good question. Try Python 3.2 EXE. Also seems like older version has binary packages (wheels) available for Python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4 You can also try `pip install lxml==3.4.4`

Answer (score -1):

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 69
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).